# Subsetting numerical values and special characters

Tags: regex, r

Hy guys,
I have a data.frame that looks like this:

> ```
> Gene_name      Chr_ID      Value      
>    a             1           34     
>    b        HG1497_PATCH     12      
>    c             22          123    
>    d            LRG_70       34      
>    e              X          56     
>    f              Y          0.1      
>    g              6          0.12    
>  .....          .....       .......
> ```

Until 10.000 rows. 
I would like the following output:

> ```
> Gene_name      Chr_ID      Value      
>    a             1           34     
>    c             22          123    
>    e             X           56     
>    f             Y           0.1      
>    g             6           0.12    
>  .....          .....       .......
> ```

The criterion to retain rows is numerical values on column 2 (`Chr_ID`) plus `X` and `Y`.

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to remove all rows where `Chr_ID` contains any nondigit characters except `X` or `Y`, you can use

```
dat[grep("^(\\d|[XY])+$", dat$Chr_ID), ]
#   Gene_name Chr_ID  Value
# 1         a      1  34.00
# 3         c     22 123.00
# 5         e      X  56.00
# 6         f      Y   0.10
# 7         g      6   0.12
```

where `dat` is the name of your data frame.

Alternatively, if `X` and `Y` are not allowed in combination with digits, you can use

```
dat[grep("^(\\d+|X|Y)$", dat$Chr_ID), ]
```

Comment: @DavidArenburg Of course, you're right. See the update.